# Convert only some rows into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, pivot

I have following table data

```
Id  Name    Email       Address
1   abc  abc@xyz.com  abc_address
2   pqr  pqr@xyz.com  pqr_address
3   mno  mno@xyz.com  mno_address
```

Desired Output Result from above table :

```
CC1_Name CC1_Email   CC1_Address  CC2_Name  CC2_Email   CC2_Address   CC3_Name  CC3_Email     CC3_Address
  abc   abc@xyz.com  abc_address    pqr    pqr@xyz.com  pqr_address      mno    mno@xyz.com   mno_address
```

I know it is possible by using PIVOT function in SQL select query. But due to some reason I am not able to achieve it.

Comment: I am not sure about the number of records in my original table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple way like this:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(CASE WHEN Id = 1 THEN Name END) AS CC1_Name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Id = 1 THEN Email END) AS CC1_Email,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Id = 1 THEN Address END) AS CC1_Address,

    MAX(CASE WHEN Id = 2 THEN Name END) AS CC2_Name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Id = 2 THEN Email END) AS CC2_Email,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Id = 2 THEN Address END) AS CC2_Address,

    MAX(CASE WHEN Id = 3 THEN Name END) AS CC3_Name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Id = 3 THEN Email END) AS CC3_Email,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Id = 3 THEN Address END) AS CC3_Address
FROM yourTable;
```

For using a query in a dynamic way you need to use dynamic SQL like this:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '';

SELECT @sql = @sql + ',' + 'MAX(CASE WHEN Id = ' + CAST(Id AS varchar(3)) + 'THEN Name END) AS CC'+ CAST(Id AS varchar(3)) + '_Name,' 
                + 'MAX(CASE WHEN Id = ' + CAST(Id AS varchar(3)) + 'THEN Email END) AS CC' + CAST(Id AS varchar(3)) + '_Email,' 
                + 'MAX(CASE WHEN Id = ' + CAST(Id AS varchar(3)) + 'THEN Address END) AS CC' + CAST(Id AS varchar(3)) + '_Address'
FROM yourTable;

SET @sql = 'SELECT ' + SUBSTRING(@sql, 2, LEN(@sql)) + ' FROM yourTable';
EXEC(@sql);
```

Comment: thanks for your time.. just want to ask if i am not sure about the number of  records in my base table then i think this logic need to be changed.. right?

Comment: Using pivot and using `Max(CASE ...)` both are static you can change them to a dynamic query by using dynamic SQL ;).

Comment: i had ran this query but i did only get third row as the result... first  row and second row are not included in the result... Thanks ..

Comment: Thanks for your help.. :-) ... i got the result. I didn't go through the query and just posted that 1st and 2nd row were not included..